# Sorting a txt file containing strings and numbers in python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I want to sort a txt file containing both strings and numbers by ascending numbers.
example of a file:

```
Berlin 400

London 903

Oslo 905

Washington 300
```

So for example I want this file to be sorted by ascending number, like this:

```
Washington 300

Berlin 400

London 903

Oslo 905
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Exactly what part of the program are you stuck on? Can you read the file? Can you determine the alphabetic characters from the integers? Can you fill a list of all the values found? At the moment, the question is way to broad for us to answer, because you have not indicated (by showing us your code that you've started on) where the problem begins, or ends.

Comment: Please see the help-page [ask] for more information on how to create a good question.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a file `capitals.txt` with the following contents:

```
Berlin 400
London 903
Oslo 905
Washington 300
```

You could consider parsing the data into a list of [`namedtuples`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) before sorting and writing the list to an output file:

```
from collections import namedtuple

CapitalInfo = namedtuple('CapitalInfo', 'name num')

capitals = []
with open('capitals.txt', 'r') as capitals_file:
    for row in capitals_file:
        name, num_str = row.split()
        num = int(num_str)
        capitals.append(CapitalInfo(name, num))

capitals.sort(key=lambda c: (c.num, c.name))

with open('sorted_capitals.txt', 'w') as sorted_capitals_file:
    for name, num in capitals[:-1]:
        sorted_capitals_file.write(f'{name} {num}\n')
    name, num = capitals[-1]
    sorted_capitals_file.write(f'{name} {num}')
```

**What `sorted_capitals.txt` contents are after running above:**

```
Washington 300
Berlin 400
London 903
Oslo 905
```

Try it **[here](https://replit.com/@ShashSinha1/DefiniteYellowishCgibin#main.py)**.